# How to limit logging for an external package when converting from log4j to log4j2... What is the correct properties file setting?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

In log4j I have:  "log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=ERROR"

What is the equivalent properties file setting in log4j2?

Comment: This was so simple to do in log4j....

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of [`LoggerConfig`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/LoggerConfig.html) elements in `log4j2.properties` uses the syntax:

```
logger.<id>.<property_name>=<property_value>
```

where `<id>` is any string identifier (used only to group the configuration of the same `Logger`, otherwise ignored), `<property_name>` is the Java bean property you want to set (cf. [`LoggerConfig` javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/LoggerConfig.html) and its setter methods).

Hence the equivalent Log4j 2.x configuration for the one in your question is:

```
logger.1.name=org.apache.struts2
logger.1.level=ERROR
```